# Modulo operation recursive

Tags: python, recursion

To practice a little bit recursion I tried to rewrite the `modulo` function in python recursive. 
`20%6` yields `2`.

I tried to approach it the following way: add `m` to itself so often until it becomes bigger than `a`. If so, subtract `a-m` and return that value.

```
def mod1(a,m):
    if m == a:
        return 0
    elif m < a:
        return mod1(a,m+m)
    else: 
        return a - m

mod(20,6)
> -4
```

However, the problem I am having is that the `m` I add on `m` changes. In the first step of the recursion it is `6+6`, in the second iteration instead of `12+6` it is `12+12`. 
How to "keep" my original `m`, but updating the one I need to change?

Comment: check the indentation

Comment: and the name of the function, you call `mod()` and your function is `mod1`

Comment: You would need a third argument (the original value of `m`). That argument could default to `None` on the outermost call.

Comment: @depperm `mod1` should be ok?!

Comment: Isn't `20 % 6 = 2` instead of 3?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes. I tried something like `x=m` on the very first line. and then `return mod1(a,m+x)`. However, that `x` becomes updated every iteration too.

Comment: @Chrissl mod1(a,m, m_original) and then mod1(a, m+m, m), so your m_original won't change

Comment: @Chrissl, yup, that's why I said *third argument*. You could start with `mod1(a, current_m, original_m=None)`, then specify the third argument in recursive calls.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yeah. That is obvious. However, I wonder if there is a way around that?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Frederic mentioned you need a third argument

```
def mod1(a,m,i):
    if m*i == a:
        return 0
    elif m*i < a:
        return mod1(a,m,i+1)
    else: 
        return a-m*(i-1)

print(mod1(20,6,1))
```

to keep the call with two arguments make the function `def` look like

```
def mod1(a,m,i=1)
....
print(mod1(20,6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding you might want to subtract from `a`, this way `m` is constant.

```
def mod1(a,m):
    if m == a:
        return 0
    elif m < a:
        return mod1(a-m, m)
    else:
        return a
```